# xhtml doc is not reading conditional stylesheets

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, media-queries

trying to retro-fit a 2-3 year old site to make it responsive, and although everything works fine in other browsers, it won't work with IE. Done in xhtml transitional.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure  that your site is sending the correcting MIME type application/xhtml+xml ? IE in particular can fall apart due to this